# Which Silver Spoon chapters have been covered by the anime?

Tags: silver-spoon

I'm thinking of reading the Silver Spoon manga by Hiromu Arakawa, and while I'd probably start from the first chapter anyway, I'm wondering which chapters of the manga have already been covered by the anime.

Which specific chapters do the first and second seasons cover respectively? I read on Yahoo Answers that the first season goes up to the end of volume 4, but given that there's been a second season, I'd like some more information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured some further research on my part wouldn't hurt:

From a combination of checking the list of [volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Spoon_%28manga%29#Manga) and [episodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Spoon_%28manga%29#Episode_list), rereading the Yahoo Answers question I referred to earlier, looking at [Baka-Updates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=64832), and looking through the relevant parts of the manga, it seems that:

- The first "season" goes up to chapter 31, which is about up to the first half of volume 4. The chapters 30 and 31 involve Hachiken's bacon production/sale, which is covered more or less in the last episode of the first season of the Silver Spoon anime. However, I couldn't find the baseball game in the last episode of the anime anywhere in or before chapter 31 - and without reading the manga, it's hard to say if that's an anime only event or not.
- Similarly, the second season seems to start at chapter 31 (where Hachiken becomes the vice-president of the equestrian club - which happens in the first episode of the second season). It seems to end at chapter 75 (where Hachiken's mother visits), which corresponds to the events of the last episode of the second season.